# Sys.path modification or more complex issue?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch, django-settings

I have problems with importing correctly a module on appengine. My app generally uses django with app-engine-patch, but this part is task queues using only the webapp framework.

I need to import django settings for the app to work properly.

My script starts with:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('common/')
# Force Django to reload its settings.
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

# Must set this env var before importing any part of Django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

I always get this error, or something related:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named ragendja.settings_pre
```

because the settings.py file starts with

```
from ragendja.settings_pre import *
```

I think I need to add ragendja to sys.path again but I had several tries that didn't work.

Here is my directory:

```
project/
    app.yaml
    setting.py
    common/
        appenginepatch/
            ragendja/
                setting_pre.py
    myapp/
        script.py
```

Is it only a sys.path problem and how do I need to modify it with the correct syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App engine patch manipulates sys.path internally.  Background tasks bypass that code, so your path will not be ready for Django calls.  You have two choices:

- Fix the paths manually.  The [app engine documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) (see the sub-section called "Handling import path manipulation") suggests factoring the path manipulation code into a module that can be imported by your task script.
- Eliminate dependencies on django code, if possible.  If you can write your task to be pure python and/or google api calls, you're good to go.  In your case, this might mean refactoring your settings code.

Comment: I need some django models, so I can't eliminate django code.
I read the first point and the google documentation, but it doesn't really help. Can you tell me more?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
sys.path.append('common/appenginepatch')
```

since the *ragendja* is in this directory?